# Copy a tag's href into img tag's src

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I need a script that will copy the `href` attribute to a `src` of an image located in the same page. It also make a change in the s1600-h value of the a href address after copying it to the img src. Here's an example:

I want the script to change this

```
<a href="**XXX/s1600-h/XXX.jpg**"><img title="Big_3" style="border-top: 0px; border-right: 0px; background-image: none; border-bottom: 0px; float: left; padding-top: 0px; padding-left: 0px; margin: 0px 10px 10px 0px; border-left: 0px; display: inline; padding-right: 0px" border="0" alt="Big_3" src="**YYY.jpg?imgmax=800**" width="119" align="left" height="89"></a>
```

...into this

```
<a href="**XXX/s1600-h/XXX.jpg**"><img title="Big_3" style="border-top: 0px; border-right: 0px; background-image: none; border-bottom: 0px; float: left; padding-top: 0px; padding-left: 0px; margin: 0px 10px 10px 0px; border-left: 0px; display: inline; padding-right: 0px" border="0" alt="Big_3" src="**XXX/s200/XXX.jpg**" width="119" align="left" height="89"></a>
```

Comment: I suggest you make an attempt, then show us what you tried and what went wrong.

Comment: Sadly, I'm not a programmer / coder, only a hobbyist. I was just trying to figure out a way to fix a problem I'm having with my blog and thought I'd ask if anyone here could kindly propose a solution.

Comment: @Lars Sorry, this is not this kind of site, please read help (http://stackoverflow.com/tour): "Stack Overflow is a question and answer site for professional and enthusiast programmers."

Answer (score 0):

Using jquery you can do this

```
url = $('img').parent().attr('href');
$('img').attr('src',url);
```

you can add this code with some event handler.
first line of code is extracting href from anchor tag and second tag is inserting it into
img tag's src.
This code is only a basic idea to it. You can customize it as your need.

Answer (score 0):

```
$('a img').click(function(event) {
  alert($(this).find('img').attr('src'));
});
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved by adding more information on what the code does and how it helps the OP.